How to automatically create the OID (SHA-256) in MbedTLS / OpenSSL?
I am using MbedTLS in firmware.  I successfully received a remote file and an encrypted hash of it that was encrypted with a private key (via OpenSSL).  I used mbedtls_sha256() to locally make my own hash of the file and then mbedtls_pk_verify() to compare that with the encrypted hash I received.
The function mbedtls_pk_verify() fails, though.  Looking at the memory with a debugger, I can see the two hashes themselves match while paused within mbedtls_pk_verify(), but I noticed there are many bytes that precede one hash that aren't present with the other (decrypted) hash.  And I see that mbedtls_pk_verify() tries to compare those extra bytes...
I found out that these are likely "OID" bytes, used to declare the SHA-256 algorithm.  Is there a way to automatically prepend these required bytes?  Otherwise, what is the usual method of doing what I want?

Is this an RSASSA-PKCS1v1_5 signature, aka RSA "classic" or "legacy"? That does indeed use padding that includes, but is not only, the OID of the hash algorithm used; see RFC8017 9.2 especially Note 1 on page 47. I don't know mbed, but I'd be astonished if any crypto library in the past 40 years doesn't handle that signature scheme. Though I wouldn't expect it in the hash call, because hashes are used in many many contexts other than RSA-PKCS1v1_5 signatures. ...

... in OpenSSL (and Libre and Boring, presumably) in the original-deprecated RSA_{sign,verify} API it's provided directly, and the newer-preferred EVP_PKEY_{sign,verify}* API is augmented by EVP_PKEY_CTX_{set,get}_signature_md or the 'digest' parameter in EVP_PKEY_CTX_ctrl[_str]

@dave_thompson_085 Yes, MbedTLS on the embedded firmware side seems to execute the RSASSA-PKCS1v1_5 signature method, thus adding the OID bytes during the verification function to its expected encoded hash (something like: 0x00 0x01 0xFF ... 0xFF 0x00 0x30 0x31 ... [correct, decrypted hash], which matches your URL's descriptions).  So, do I need to add these OID bytes to my original OpenSSL's digesting/hashing of the firmware somehow, before its sent to the embedded device--is that typical?

“encrypted with a private key” is nonsense (but it's nonsense that people have done, so you may well be stuck with a bad protocol). You can use a private key to decrypt or sign, and you can use a public key to encrypt or verify. mbedtls_pk_verify wants a PKCS#1v1.5 signature, but what you're feeding it is evidently not a signature. What is the content of the data that you receive after RSA decoding (i.e. the complete hex dump that ends with the hash)? Do you have the code that calls openssl to produce this data?

@Gilles I am learning more as I go along; I understand now that there is formalized terminology involved.  "Signature" in this case means a hash that has padding and OID bytes appended, I believe?  However, I'd argue that “encrypted with a private key” is not nonsense...I can "encrypt a hash with a private key" just as I might encrypt my gandma's shoe size, no?  Of course, those wouldn't be "signatures", which is why mbedtls_pk_verify() failed me.

@Gilles The difference between encrypting a hash and making a proper signature is where I got lost (see my answer).

I found out that mbedtls_pk_verify() failed in MbedTLS because I used the wrong command in OpenSSL to create my original encrypted hash/signature.  I used openssl dgst... when I needed to use openssl sha256 -sign...  This added the required (signature) bytes that MbedTLS' mbedtls_pk_verify() was looking for.  Thanks to all respondents for helping me figure it out.

FYI: openssl $hash -sign rsapriv or equivalently openssl dgst -$hash -sign rsapriv is the better way, but openssl $hash -binary | openssl pkeyutl -sign -pkeyopt digest:$hash -inkey rsapriv also correctly does PKCS1v1_5, whereas openssl $hash -binary | openssl rsautl -sign -inkey rsapriv doesn't. If you'd put that in your Q I could have told you right away.

@dave_thompson_085 Thanks for your answers.  I didn't know I needed to put that in my original question as I was new to this realm.  I was blaming my firmware when I created the problem way back on my computer!
